# Storing undetermined amounts of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've been looking into the best way of storing an undetermined amount of information submitted by a user. A friend of mine suggested using nested tables, however these don't appear to be a thing in MySQL.

The application will allow users to store pieces of text information per day (each day is a blank slate so to speak)

What I have currently is

```
-Users
--ID
--email
--password

-Things
--UID (made from date and user ID)
--Thing1
--Thing2
```

This works fine. The UID is the users ID and the date combined (i.e 71420150404) as each day will be different but I'm open to changing this. The application checks to see if there are any entries for that UID and if there isn't, creates a new row.

The problem I have is I'd like the user to be able to select how many pieces of information they would like to add per day. So instead of the static 'Thing1, Thing2' the user could theoretically have this go up to 'Thing100', and I'm fairly sure adding these as columns isn't the best way to go about this.

I looked into if its possible to store an array in a cell and I'd access it like that through PHP but the research I came across all suggests I shouldn't do this. Creating a new table per user also seems very inefficient.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: uid, thing_slot,thing

Comment: Split your `uid` into `user_id` and `date` - makes it easier to filter by user.

Comment: Can you provide some context on the type of data the user is storing? strings, integers, longs pieces of text, image files, binary files? Also what are the read/search requirements of the data once it's in the database? Will the service need to query the things table for 'user_stuff = 'Thing1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create 2 tables:
entry table: id (auto increment), user id, timestamp - each time a user wants to store things a record is created and the id is retrieved using last_insert_id()

things table: id (auto increment), entry_id (foreign key to entry table), thing ( to store whatever the user wants to store)

If a user wants to store 10 things, then you create an entry record, then using its id you create 10 records within the things table. This way you are completely flexible on the number of things a user can store.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say create a new record, are you suggesting a new row per thing? A user will have for example, 10 things a day, how would I reference a single thing/entry for that day?

Comment: Yep, each thing is stored in a record. The entry id will determine which records in the things table belong to an entry.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, I'll try and work this out tomorrow after work. I'll wait to see if anyone has other suggestions before marking this as the answer.

Comment: @jblz this is basic normalisation. I don't think that there's much else that can be said that hasn't been said a thousand times already!